# Make div same height as text

Tags: html, css

I would like the div .omschrijving to have the same height as the text in it.

This is my current HTML:

```
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Mundo Melocoton Short Aqua Blauw enzo bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.aProduct {
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dcd8d7;
}

.aProduct .omschrijving {
    line-height: 26px;
    background: #cac;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is the current result:

[image: div height of text]

So as you can see, when the text becomes too long, the div doesn't increase in height. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The HTML you provided doesn't match the result you're showing .. Can you give us the exact HTML you're using to get that screenshot?

Comment: As the first comment said, the code you provided doesn't reflect the problem you are having. You should provide all relevant code, as I just tried the code you gave and there is no problem with it.

Comment: I just found out what caused problem... It is because I used a piece of jQuery to give both multiple divs the same height. However, this jQuery code was only supposed to be applied within a certain media query, however I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `height` attribute. This effect occurs when you specify height of element, but inner content is higher than parent.